# react-native-webview scroll not coming in android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I am  using expo and having a expo react-native-webview inside a scrollview, below is the return of component that is returning webview .
what i am doing is creating screen in that i want to parse my html and show on screen in containers.
The design of containers is in parent screens in which this component is called .
Question 1:  I have tried multiple solutions for getting scroll inside  webview in android devices but nothing is working .
below code is working perfect with IOS devices.

Question 2: Can we restrict webview to show only 5 lines on view and turncate rest to (... ) ?
can some one help ?

```
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={["*"]}
        source={{ html: htmlContent }}
        style={styles.WebViewStyle}
      />

    </View>

  );

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  WebViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 5,
    height: 150,
    width: '100%',

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And finally i need to move on another way for fix.
As i was using scrollview and webview was child for that it was working fine for IOS but android  webview was not scrolling.
Problem was both scrollview was webview was trying to take the screen height and getting conficted.
So i moved the webview out of scroll view.